# loop through column glmer

Tags: r, loops, glm

I am trying to run a glmer by looping through columns in my dataset which contain response variables (dat_prob).The code I am using is as follows, adapted from code researched on another stackoverflow question ([Looping through columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425246/looping-through-columns-in-r)).

Their code:

```
dat_y<-(dat[,c(2:1130)])
dat_x<-(dat[,c(1)])
models <- list()
#
for(i in names(dat_y)){
      y <- dat_y[i]
     model[[i]] = lm( y~dat_x )
    }
```

My code:

```
dat_prob<-(probs[,c(108:188)])
dat_age<-(probs[,c(12)]) 
dat_dist<-(probs[,c(20)]) 
fyearcap=(probs[,c(25)]) 
fstation=(probs[,c(22)]) 
fnetnum=(probs[,c(23)]) 
fdepth=(probs[,c(24)]) 

models <- list() 
#
for(i in names(dat_prob)){
  y <- dat_prob[i]
  y2=as.vector(y)
  model[[i]] = glmer( y ~ dat_age * dat_dist + (1|fyearcap) + (1|fstation)+
  (1|fnetnum)+ (1|fdepth),family=binomial,REML=TRUE )
}
```

And I receive this error, similar to the error received in the hyperlinked question:

```
Error in model.frame.default(drop.unused.levels = TRUE, formula = y ~  :
invalid type (list) for variable 'y'
```

I have been working through this for hours and now can't see the forest through the trees.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would be better of putting everything in a data.frame and iterate over that. Or, you could construct formulas in advance (no need to subset the data) and pass that to the `glmer` function. You can flip through a list of formulas using `sapply` or `lapply`.

Answer (score 0):

`y <- dat_prob[i]` makes `y` a list (or data frame, whatever). Lists are vectors - try `is.vector(list())`, so even `y2 = as.vector(y)` is still a list/data frame (even though you don't use it).

```
class(as.vector(mtcars[1]))
# [1] "data.frame"
```

To extract a numeric vector from a data frame, use `[[`: `y <- dat_prob[[i]]`.

```
class(mtcars[[1]])
# [1] "numeric"
```

Though I agree with Roman - using formulas is probably a nicer way to go. Try something like this:

```
for(i in names(dat_prob)) {
  my_formula = as.formula(paste(i,
    "~ dat_age * dat_dist + (1|fyearcap) + (1|fstation)+ (1|fnetnum)+ (1|fdepth)"
  ))
  model[[i]] = glmer(my_formula, family = binomial, REML = TRUE)
}
```

I'm also pretty skeptical of whatever you're doing trying 80 different response variables, but that's not your question...